# Using "cygcheck" to "find the package to which FILE belongs"

Tags: cygwin

According to my Cygwin setup program "setup-x86_64.exe", I have package `texlive-collection-latexextra` version 20220321-1.  The Cygwin package search [page](https://cygwin.com/packages/) says that this package should contain `usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changes/changes.sty`, whch I confirmed.

The output from `cygcheck --help` says that `cygcheck -f FILE [FILE]...` will "find the package to which FILE belongs".  However, `cygcheck -f changes.sty` returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following as the script `/usr/local/bin/cygsearch` (with `/usr/local/bin` in my `$PATH`, obviously)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <program_name>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cygcheck -p "/$1"
```

This version uses an online repository search for the specified file, returning a list of packages where there is a match. For example,

```
cygsearch date.exe
Found 6 matches for /date.exe
coreutils-debuginfo-8.26-2 - coreutils-debuginfo: Debug info for coreutils
coreutils-debuginfo-8.32-1 - coreutils-debuginfo: Debug info for coreutils
coreutils-debuginfo-9.0-1 - coreutils-debuginfo: Debug info for coreutils
coreutils-8.26-2 - coreutils: GNU core utilities (includes fileutils, sh-utils and textutils)
coreutils-8.32-1 - coreutils: GNU core utilities (includes fileutils, sh-utils and textutils)
coreutils-9.0-1 - coreutils: GNU core utilities (includes fileutils, sh-utils and textutils)
```

You don't always need to include the `.exe` suffix, but without it I find I often get too many false positives for the results I'm expecting

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to specify the *full path* of the file:

```
# Nothing gets listed
cygcheck -f changes.sty

# Nothing gets listed
cygcheck -f \
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changes/changes.sty

# Package is listed
cygcheck -f \
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changes/changes.sty

  texlive-collection-latexextra-20220321-1
```